# Laravel 4 Cashier: Don't fire webhook if initiated from laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm using Laravel 4 with Cashier 2.0 and its webhook controller. I want to prevent following behavior: When I create a new subscription for a user within my laravel application, this turns out to execute the method subscription.updated webhook.

However I want to prevent that the webhooks are executed if the request was made within the laravel application. The webhooks should only execute if there were initiated from the Stripe admin panel directly. Someone that can help me with this?

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I don't agree, this question is detailed enough from my opinion. I have explained the problem, and what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you would want to do that. The point of the webhooks are to confirm actions have been received and successfully (or unsuccessfully) completed by Stripe so you know certain things have happened (i.e: A user has successfully been subscribed to a subscription, a charge has happened on a users card, etc.). All of this depends on your application successfully communicating with stripe and stripe successfully billing the card, many things could happen in that processes and the webhooks are there for you to be able to confirm what happened, and if it went wrong, what went wrong.

The behaviour you're after cannot be achieved without your application making no communications with Stripe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer wader. However I have been in contact with Stripe and they told me that the behavior I want is not possible. However I do think that its not a special case.

What I have at the moment is that a user can subscribe/upgrade/downgrade/cancel a plan using the Laravel Cashier library (which is using the API), and this works well. But I also have the possibility as a admin to change the subscription from the Stripe admin panel. Both actions will execute the API, and both will trigger the webhook.

Comment: It's logic that when a user subscribed to a plan using my application (Laravel Cashier), I will know synchronously if he was able to or not. So I don't want to be reconfirmed by the webhook that its plan changed. However if I as a admin would update the plan, I need the webhook to let my application know that the plan changed.

Comment: Thats true, but if stripe is handling your billing you need stripe to be in sync with your own application to bill the user for the correct amount. So if your application for whatever reason fails to communicate with stripe then the two are out of sync, your application knows the user is on 1 subscription plan, but stripe could be billing an incorrect amount because it never got the message to update the users subscription to a new level